# plotting arrows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I can draw two points in space and place arrows at them:

```
plot(1,1,'o','MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor','k','MarkerSize',5,'LineWidth',1.5); hold on; 
plot(2,1,'o','MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor','k','MarkerSize',5,'LineWidth',1.5); hold on; 



vec1=zeros(1,3); vec2=zeros(1,3); col1=zeros(1,3); col2=zeros(1,3);
vec1=[0.98996547   0.00000000    0.14130945];

vec2=[0.00000000    0.70710678   -0.70710678];


col1= [abs(vec1(1,1)) abs(vec1(1,2)) abs(vec1(1,3))];
col2= [abs(vec2(1,1)) abs(vec2(1,2)) abs(vec2(1,3))];


scalef=0.4;
quiver3(1,1,0,vec1(1,1)*scalef,vec1(1,2)*scalef,vec1(1,3)*scalef,'AutoScale','off', 'MaxHeadSize',5,'LineWidth',5,'Color',col1); hold on;

quiver3(2,1,0,vec2(1,1)*scalef,vec2(1,2)*scalef,vec2(1,3)*scalef,'AutoScale','off','MaxHeadSize',5,'LineWidth',5,'Color',col2); hold on; 
view(20,20);
hold off;
```

The beginning of each arrow is the black point. How can I move the beginning of the arrow before the point so that the visual effect is better? Stated otherwise how can I place the points in the body of the arrow?

[image]

Comment: This would be a good place to add an image or two

Comment: @MadPhysicist image added

Comment: Is the image what you're getting or what you want?

Comment: what I am getting, I want the arrows to begin before the black dots, so that the dots are on the arrow's body.

Comment: Shift the point along your vector: something like `p1_shifted = [1 1 0] - a_constant * vec1`. Noticed also that `hold on` need to be called only once.

Comment: @obchardon I was wondering if there is an automated way to do that

Comment: Put your points and your vectors in a 2D array: `vec = [1 2 3; 4 5 6], p = [1 1 1; 2 2 2]` and shift everything at once: `p_shift = p - a_constant * vec`, then plot the result with just one line : `quiver3(p_shift(:,1), p_shift(:,2)...`)